# Showing that two circles in w-plane tangent each other if there is a Möbius transformation that takes them to two parallel lines

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I want to show that two parallel lines in z-plane yield two   tanging  circles in w-plane. I start with two lines, $L_1=i+x$ and  $L_2=3i+x$.  Then I want to use the formula:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}
\end{equation}

and having the points on the lines:

$P_1=i, i+1, i+2 $, $P_2=3i,3i+1,3i+2$, I have the right hand side of that equation set. But the left hand side is not so easy to see which points I have to choose. I propose the following for line 1, $L_1=i+x:$

$z_1= i, w_1=i; z_2=i+1, w_2=1; z_3=i+2, w_3=\infty$

I insert in

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}
\end{equation}

For the case of line 1:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-i)(1-\infty)}{(w-\infty)(1-i)}=\frac{(z-i)(i+1-i-2)}{(z-i-2)(i+1-i)}
\end{equation}

gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-i)}{(1-i)}=\frac{(z-i)(i+1-i-2)}{(z-i-2)(i+1-i)}
\end{equation}

which gives the Möbius transformation

\begin{equation}
w=\frac{(2 - i) - (1 - 2 i) z}{-2 - i) + z}
\end{equation}
which has the given w-plot:

[image: C1]

Then line 2, $L_2=3i+x$:

$z_1= 3i, w_1=3i; z_2=3i+1, w_2=3i+1; z_3=3i+2, w_3=\infty$

I insert in

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}
\end{equation}
I insert in

$z_1= 3i, w_1=3i; z_2=3i+1, w_2=3i+1; z_3=3i+2, w_3=\infty$

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-3i)(w_2-\infty)}{(w-\infty)(3i+1-3i)}=\frac{(z-3i)(3i+1-3i-2)}{(z-3i-2)(3i+1-3i)}
\end{equation}

which gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-3i)}{(3i+1-3i)}=\frac{(z-3i)(3i+1-3i-2)}{(z-3i-2)(3i+1-3i)}
\end{equation}

which results in

\begin{equation}
w=\frac{(9 - 3 i) - (1 - 3 i) z)}{(-2 - 3 i) + z)}
\end{equation}

Which has the following w-plot:

[image: C2]

Together, they give:

[image: C1C2]

But I am not so sure the tangent each other. What did go wrong in the choice of w-data?

UPDATE:

By Martins proposition, we take two circles in z-plane, which tangent each other at z=1, $|z|=1 and |z-2|=1$.

We have the new data:

C1: $z_1=0$, $z_2=i$, $z_3=1$; $w_1=0, w_2=i, w_3=\infty$

gives  the form of w:

\begin{equation}
w=\frac{-zi-z}{(z-1)(i)}
\end{equation}

which has the given plot
[image: CC1]

and the second circle, C2:

C2: $z_1=2, z_2=i+2, z_3=1; w_1=2, w_2=i+2, w_3=\infty$

which gives the form:

\begin{equation}
w=\frac{(z-2)(i+1)}{(z-1)}+2
\end{equation}

which has the given plot:

[image: CC2]

together they give the plot:

[image: C1CC2]

Comment: Fine...  More clear with  thinner lines.

Comment: If $C_1, C_2$ are two circles which are tangent to each other at $z_0$ then $T(z) = 1/(z-z_0)$ is a Möbius transformation which takes the circles to parallel lines. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: In your question body you start with two lines and then construct two Möbius transformations which transform these lines to other lines. It is unclear to me how that is related to the question in the title.

Comment: Your first point, without the T(z) part. It is more like your second point.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Is your real question what is stated in the title? That “two circles in w-plane tangent each other if there is a Möbius transormation that takes them to two parallel lines”?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Narasimham
 Check the new plots

Comment: Thanks. New plots are nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C_1, C_2$ are two circles in the plane which are tangent to each other then they intersect exactly at one point $w_0 \in \Bbb C$. Then $T(w) = 1/(w-w_0)$ is a Möbius transformation which maps the two circles to two (extended) lines. These lines are parallel because they intersect only at $T(w_0) = \infty$.

Conversely, if $C_1, C_2$ are two circles in the plane and $T$ is a Möbius transformation which maps them to parallel lines then $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect only at the single point $T^{-1}(\infty)$, which means that they are tangent to each other.

Comment: This is great, thanks, but how did you identify T(w), except from experience?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: Any Möbius transformation with $T(w_0) = \infty$ would do. The only requirement is that the intersection point of the circles is mapped to the point at infinity. (In other words: experience :)

Comment: The intersection point would be $w_3$, that is given as $\infty$ in my example. Is it wrong as such?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: Your calculation (as I read it) maps two *lines,* and $z_3 = i+2$ resp. $3i+2$ is mapped to $w_3=\infty$. If you had started with two touching *circles* and chosen $z_3$ as the intersection point then it might have worked.

Comment: Two circles in z-plane, that would be $|z|=1$ and $|z|=3$ for instance?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: $|z|=1$ and $|z|=3$ are not tangent to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132482/discussion-between-viola-player-and-martin-r).